# unable to get auth state ionic angular firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Hi I am using `"@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",` and `"firebase": "^9.19.1",` and `"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",`. I need help to find the user sate once user is logged in.

Here is my code:

```
import {
    Auth,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    User,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    user: User | null = null;
    
  constructor(private auth: Auth) { 
    this.auth.authstate.subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }
```

Before i used to use `AngularFireAuth` importing from `'@angular/fire/compat/auth'
with the recent update https://github.com/angular/angularfire

I am getting error to find the authstate of user and the error is `Property 'authstate' does not exist on type 'Auth'.`

Can you please help me to find what do I need to update in order to get user state when the user status is logged in and out.

Comment: New api is `this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) =>...`

Comment: The property is named `authState`, but you spelled it `authSate`. See https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth.md#authstate

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry it was error while posting the question I have updated it. The error is same after the updating the spell.

Comment: Please don't type code just for the question, but copy/paste the actual code you have in a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Now your question spells it `authstate`, while the property is actually named `authState` with an uppercase `S`.